# Construct a Vector of any Type with a Trait Constraint

Tags: rust, traits

I'd like to have a struct, with a member that is a Vec with a Trait Constraint on the types in the Vector.  Right now, this is what I am trying:

```rust
pub trait SomeTrait {
    fn some_function(&self);
}

pub struct SomeStruct<T: SomeTrait> {
    member: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: SomeTrait> SomeStruct<T> {
    pub fn new() -> SomeStruct<T> {
        SomeStruct {
            member: Vec::new()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut some_struct = SomeStruct::new();
}
```

And the compiler is giving me:

```
error: the trait 'sometrait::SomeTrait' is not implemented for the type '_'
let mut some_struct = SomeStruct::new();
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
note: required by 'somestruct::SomeStruct<T>::new'
let mut some_struct = SomeStruct::new();
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I've tried placing `<T: SomeTrait>` in various places throughout, but just getting even stranger compiler errors, so those attempts must be way off base.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does the impl need to implement some_function? (Wild guess.)

Comment: From what I understand, the elements in the `some_struct.member` vector need to implement `some_function`, not necessarily the struct.  At least, that is what I'm aiming for... but, I have no idea what the syntax is for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't given the compiler enough information to figure out what `T` is.  That's what the `_` is for: it's having to infer the parameter to `SomeStruct`.

Also, there are no types anywhere in this example that implement `SomeTrait`.  If you fix both of these problems, it works (with some warnings):

```
pub trait SomeTrait {
    fn some_function(&self);
}

pub struct SomeStruct<T: SomeTrait> {
    member: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: SomeTrait> SomeStruct<T> {
    pub fn new() -> SomeStruct<T> {
        SomeStruct {
            member: Vec::new()
        }
    }
}

impl SomeTrait for i32 {
    fn some_function(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut some_struct_a: SomeStruct<i32> = SomeStruct::new();
    let mut some_struct_b = SomeStruct::<i32>::new();
}
```

Comment: Does this not limit me to only having `i32` types in the `some_struct.member` vector?  Since it is the only type that is currently implementing `SomeTrait`?

Comment: Rust is not dynamically typed; the way you've written `SomeStruct` means it cannot support values of multiple types.  Also, you can't use a type as `T` if it doesn't implement `SomeTrait`, so I'm not sure what your concern in this case is.  If you want to support values of different types in the `Vec`, you'll need to look at using some kind of indirection (`Box`, `Rc`, `&`, etc.).

Comment: That's what I was trying to ask for clarity on, if there was a way to write that `struct` and `impl` sections so that `member` would represent a Vec of any type that implemented `SomeTrait`.  Thought that may have been an option, but I guess not.

Comment: It *is* a `Vec` of any type that implements `SomeTrait`... as in, the `T` in `Vec<T>` can be any one type.  What I suspect you're asking for is a `Vec` of `SomeTrait`.  You can't do that, but you can do things like `Box<SomeTrait>` or `&'a SomeTrait`, among other options.  There's also `enum`s.